# Adding External jars to Anypoint studio

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule4

I need to add external vendor specific jar to generate custom signature as per vendor.However the jar has internal dependencies on 5-6 other jars like commons lang ,gson etc.

I added the jars via ->build path-> add external jars. But while invoking the function via dataweave its throwing exception (class not found etc because of internal reference of this jar to multiple other jars).

If I try to add these generic(commons lang etc) dependencies etc.. it is searching in mule repo instead of maven repo.

Can anyone help me with the exact steps for importing these jars correctly ? Is it a hard and fast rule to import jars via Maven only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule 4 projects are Maven based exclusively. You have to add dependencies via Maven. Adding them in Studio build path will fail at execution time.